# Show that this function is not continuous except on a set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a enumeration over the rationals

Let 
$$g(x)=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_n}} \chi_{(0,1]}$$
where 
$$\chi_{(0,1]} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1&\mbox{if $x-r_n \in (0,1]$,}\\
0&\mbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$

Show that $g$ is not continuous except possibly on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Hint: If $g$ were continuous on a set of positive measure, then it would be continuous on a compact set with positive measure. Think about what compact sets with positive measures in $\mathbb{R}^1$ need to look like, and show that this can't be true.

Comment: Hint: Show the function is unbounded on any interval.

Comment: @Zarrax You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Zarrax noted, the function 
$$g(x)=\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}} \chi_{(0,1]}$$
is unbounded on every open interval, because any such interval contains some $r_n$.

On the other hand, $g$ is integrable, because the integral of the $n$th term is bounded by a multiple of $2^{-n}$. Therefore, $g$ is finite almost everywhere.

Conclusion: $g$ is discontinuous at every point where it's finite, which is almost everywhere. (It is continuous in the extended sense at each $r_n$, since both the limit and the value are $+\infty$.)