# Give me a example of a function Lebesgue Integrable over [a,b] that is not bounded in any subinterval of [a,b]

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Give me a example of a function Lebesgue Integrable over [a,b] that is not bounded in any subinterval of [a,b].

*I'm thinking about this but without progress...

Comment: You can use the function defined [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20715/show-that-this-function-is-not-continuous-except-on-a-set-of-measure-zero). (It's a bit more than what you need.)

Comment: My first thought is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty w_k/(x-q_k)$ where $q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots$ are all the rationals in $[0,1]$ and the weights $w_k$ are chosen so as to make the series converge almost everywhere.  I don't know whether such a sequence of weights exists, but if so, that ought to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=0,\ x\in{\Bbb R}\backslash{\Bbb Q}$

$f(r/s)=s$, $r/s$ irreducible fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What if the function gets arbitrarily large on a dense subset of $[a,b]$ of measure zero?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a countable, dense subset $\{x_k\}$ of $[a,b]$, and set

$ f = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-k}}{\sqrt{|x-x_k|}}$.

Each summand is measurable and positive, so $f$ is a monotone limit of measurable functions. Moreover, if you integrate $f$ you can use the monotone convergence theorem to exchange the sum and integral. Finally, since

$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{|x-x_k|}} \le 2\sqrt{b-a}$,

you find that $\int_a^b f\hspace{2pt}dx$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an enumeration of the rationals, and define your function to be $ n $ at the $ n $-th  rational and $0$ on all the irrationals.  Then this function is zero almost everywhere, but as every non-trivial interval $ I$ contains infinitely many rationals, it must also be unbounded on  each such $ I $.